# Using basic authentication with the gate service

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I'm trying to integrate an automated tool with spinnaker through the gate API. Right now I have oauth2 enabled for the regular UI flow and am looking how to setup basic auth for my tool.

I couldn't find on the docs how or if this is possible at all. I've also tried reusing a session token but it doesn't work as the cookie can be reset when spinnaker redeploys.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable basic authentication by changing the file `.hal/<deployment-name>/profiles/gate-local.yml`:

```
security:
  basicform:
    enabled: true
  user:
    name: <username you want>
    password: <password you want>
```

and the file `.hal/<deployment-name>/profiles/settings-local.js`:

```
window.spinnakerSettings.authEnabled = true;
```